# configuration sessionfactory in hibernate 6

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

i am using hibernate 6 with spring boot 3 and i have problem to create sessionfactory bean programmicaly

now i try to create session factory with Configuration, but spring boot make error for datasource missing

in hibernate 5 i used LocalSessionFactory class to create session factory , now this class removed,so what can i do to create sessionfactory programmicaly?

what is equivalent of this code in hibernate 6 ?

```
  @Bean
    LocalSessionFactoryBean gSessionFactory() {
        LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
        sessionFactory.setDataSource(getDatasource());
        sessionFactory.setHibernateProperties(configuration());
        sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan(new String[] { "com.jewerly.onlineshop.Model" });
        return sessionFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    DataSource getDatasource() {
        DataSourceBuilder datasource = DataSourceBuilder.create();
        datasource.username("root");
        datasource.url("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mehdi");
        datasource.password("Mehdi.7465");
        return datasource.build();
    }

    @Bean
    HibernateTransactionManager transaction() {
        HibernateTransactionManager tr = new HibernateTransactionManager();
        tr.setSessionFactory(gSessionFactory().getObject());
        tr.setDataSource(getDatasource());
        return tr;
    }
```